# Just bought a domain, setting up a couple server applications for the first time

Tags: domains, security, subdomain

I recently bought a domain, mainly for website experimentation, game servers and a ventrillo server. I'm running all this from my home computer, and I am using freedns.afraid.org as my dns nameserver. I'm able to host my ventrillo and my game server, however you can access either of them from any of my subdomains. I would like specific programs to only work with specific ports, but I can't seem to find a way to make this happen. So in my Ventrillo subdomain, I try putting in the IP address in the destination as "MyIPAddress:PortNumber" , but it says its an invalid IP address. The ddns client I use doesn't have any options to change the ports on the connections either. Am I just missing something here, or is there no way to tie specific server applications to specific ports with a subdomain?

I also am curious as to how hosting this domain will affect my pc security. I'm running this on a Windows 7 pc. I know its best to have a stand alone computer for this stuff, but like I said its only experimental and I don't plan on running these more than a couple hours a day, if that. Are there any steps I need to take to increase my security, beyond basic Windows security measures?

Comment: If you want to change the port number that each app/service is accessed from, then you need to do that in that app's server configurations. It has nothing to do with subdomains or DDNS. DNS can only point your domain to a particular IP or another hostname. It doesn't specify the port. Anyways, if you want to ask questions about networking, server configurations or security, you should ask those questions at [serverfault](http://serverfault.com).